# Denver Meetup Interest?

Tags: discussion

I noticed there are several of us based in Denver and would love to meet up. Is there any interest out there? Before/after the holidays? I would propose Rock Bottom Brewery as it is a large and accommodating space, and a date of either the 18th of December or after the New Year.

I created a [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32962/meetups) where we can plan meetups at a more general level.

Comment: There is the [Denver Salesforce Developer Group](http://www.meetup.com/Denver-Salesforce-Platform-Developer-User-Group/) that typically meets once per month... Or are you looking for something else?

Comment: I would be interested in this if it was geared towards marketing cloud. I know there are a lot of SFMC users around that area of downtown as well.

Comment: @sfdcfox I wasn't aware of that. I'll take a look, thanks!

Comment: @JonSakas I personally don't know much about SFMC but would be curious to learn more.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Also, DSDG is a *sanctioned* salesforce.com event (i.e. salesforce.com actually funds those events, has internal employees visit, gives out free goodies, etc), although there's nothing stopping people from organizing an unofficial meeting for those that want a different format. Usually DSDG focuses on things like upcoming technology/features and so on, more than focusing on existing features and disseminating information that would help novices. I think it could be a pretty good networking event for those that miss DSDG because of timing or space limitations.

Comment: @sfdcfox I was also thinking of a more social aspect, it can be fun to see who else is involved.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I do agree with that. I love meeting the people as DSDG (also sometimes called DUG, Denver User Group), and it's great meeting people with the same interests (at least, professionally). I'd be happy to show up at such an event if I were able to make it.